Should I be asking for a percentage of the sales of software I've keep design for a partner company
I wanted some advice regarding some work my company has asked me to do for a partner company. Someone suggested I should ask for a percentage of the sales, but wanted to ask what other options there are.
I've been asked to help design some new software which the partner company will then develop. This will be using many years of experience and expertise on my part. My company will be charging the partner company for my time, so they will get their reimbursement. I am a consultant at my company, but my job title is team lead so this is out of my remit.
Once completed the partner company will sell the product, with my company managing the admin.
I have been advised to ask for a percentage of the sales once it goes to market, but I wanted to check if there was a better option. Should I ask for shares or a bonus etc.

You can ask for anything you want. Unless you're actually, truly, one of the very best people in your world in your area of expertise, the answer will be "no".

VTC as opinion based

Remember that once any software is written, it is out of date and needs to be updated. I find that charging regular time for all the updates, feature enhancements, special customer requests, etc. can be as substantial as getting a percentage of the sales and is easier to charge for.

Agreed, "should any one individual try this"  is definitely opinion. But in general, the answer is going to be that your salary already reflects your value to the company. Salesman used to negotiate for a bonus based on their sales, but companies would pay them a lower base salary to offset

You have been advised by someone that doesn't know what they are talking about.


I have been advised to ask for a percentage of the sales once it goes
to market, but I wanted to check if there was a better option. Should
I ask for shares or a bonus etc.

In your current role, your salary is your reward. Asking for a percent of sales isn't something you do after the fact, while working for an employer.
If you think your design skills are significant enough to command a royalty, you should be working on your own.
Quit your current company. Form your own design company. Market yourself as a superior designer. Sign contracts for royalties.

That depends on what your contract says and your local labor laws. I suggest studying both carefully.
Many contracts specifically exclude this type of thing. You get paid for your work and the work product belongs fully to whoever pays you.
Some contracts allow you to work elsewhere. If that 's the case, you can try cutting out your current employer and negotiate a separate contract directly with the partner company. You can try to negotiate whatever you want, but whether they go for it or not is anyone's guess. That's what negotiation is all about.
Since they are a partner company of your current employer, its unlikely that you can get anything out of this other than your regular compensation.
